# "Does not name a type" error in class

Tags: c++, class, struct, compiler-errors

I'm writing a program for my class which involves using a class inside of a struct. When defining the struct (named polynomial) 'Polynomial does not name a type'. It triggers on the first line of the default constructor:

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(){
    coefs = vector<Fraction>();
}
```

Specifically the error occurs on the "Polynomial::Polynomial(){" line.

All other examples I've found for this error include `using class B` inside class A before class B is declared. The only member of Polynomial is a vector of class Fractions. I have tried forward declaration of class Fractions and vector is included. This is probably a rookie mistake as I am still very new to C++ classes (this being my first one) so any help would be appreciated.

The relevant portion of the polynomial header file is:

```
// data members
vector<Fraction> coefs;

// methods
Polynomial() = default;
```

Comment: You are trying to define a default constructor when you explicitly told the compiler to do it for you (`Polynomial() = default;`).

Comment: Can you give us a bit more to go on? That error could happen for a few reasons. Is Polynomial the class inside another class? Did you `#include` the header file in the source file? Let's see more of your code.

Comment: That constructor is completely unnecessary anyway, since `coefs` will use the default `vector<Fraction>` constructor when the default `Polynomial` constructor runs.

Comment: I thought the default might be the issue so I have also tried it without the coefs definition and the error still occurs, It seems the error is happening in the line above that. Fraction is the class being used inside of the struct polynomial. All files are included but that doesn't mean I included them correctly. Here are some screenshots: http://puu.sh/gEnLp/8198bc64ae.png    http://puu.sh/gEnPj/e740c0a044.png The Fraction header and cpp files are almost certainly not the issue as they were provided by the instructor.

Comment: Where do you `#include "polynomial.h"` ?

Comment: *sigh* well I knew it was something stupid. That was it Matt, thanks a bunch. Figured out in a couple seconds/minutes whats been aggravating me for a couple hours.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [does not name a type error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026047/c-errors-class-does-not-name-a-type-and-invalid-use-of-incomplete-type)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Not at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`polynomial.cpp` needs to include it's header:

```
#include "polynomial.h"
```

There is no implicit association between the source (.cpp file) and the header (.h) file in C++. You must include the header for the name `Polynomial` to be understood.